# How can I access to FirebaseAuth user password with the getter in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to access the User password to set on User default constructor, because I make it required

```
import 'package:project_app/user/password.dart';
import 'package:project_app/user/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as firebase;

extension FirebaseUserDomainX on firebase.User {
  User toDomain() {
    return User(
      id: UniqueId.fromUniqueIdString(uid),
      email: EmailAddress.fromEmailString(email),
      password: Password.fromPasswordString(firebase.UserCredential.password),
    );
  }
}
```

> Output error

```
The getter 'password' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'
```

Comment: you're not allowed to access it

Comment: That would be bad if you could do that.